# Flex 4 - Wrapping text around an Image

Tags: apache-flex, image, flex4, word-wrap

Is it possible to wrap text around an image? Here is a [link](http://www.monkeydoit.com/wrap-text-images-html.php) of what I would like to do with Flex, not HTML as in the example. Will it be possible to use the `textFlow` component like we tried here?

```
<s:TextArea width="100%" height="100%" editable="false">
 <s:textFlow>
  <s:TextFlow>
   <s:img source="imageLocation" width="80" height="80" />
   <s:p textAlign="justify">text_goes_here</s:p>
  </s:TextFlow>
 </s:textFlow>
</s:TextArea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work out of the box with TLF.

You could use 2 linked ControlerContainer as explained here  :
http://forums.adobe.com/message/2705930#2705930